# npm run generate した際に dist フォルダ内の html ファイルが変更されない

Tags: html, vue.js, npm, nuxt.js

vue.jsでwebアプリの開発を行っています。
firebase-hostingにアップロードするため、npm run generate を実行しました。
distフォルダにhtmlファイルが生成されるのですが、一部分だけがhtmlに反映されません。
具体的には`v-stepper-content`のstep1,step2は変更されますが、step3,step4が変更されません。
`npm run dev`を実行し、local環境では問題なく表示されます。

*画像の説明*
27行目辺り→**野菜の名前**という日本語が表示されている
31~34が本来step3の内容が表示されるはず。**単位▽**や*円*といった情報が表示されるはず…？

`npm run generate`した際の出力先は**nuxt.config.js**で**dist**フォルダに指定しています。

```
<v-stepper-content step="2" class="pa-3">
        <v-card>
          <v-row
            v-for="item in newvegenamelist"
            :key="item.id">
            <v-col cols="12">
              <v-text-field
                v-model="item.name"
                label="野菜の名前"></v-text-field>
            </v-col>
          </v-row>
          <v-row>
            <v-col cols="6"></v-col>
            <v-col cols="3" class="pr-1">
              <v-btn
                @click="addInput"
                width="100%"
                color="grey">
                <v-icon dark>
                  mdi-plus
                </v-icon>
              </v-btn>
            </v-col>
            <v-col cols="3" class="pl-1">
              <v-btn
                @click="removeInput"
                width="100%"
                color="grey">
                <v-icon dark>
                  mdi-minus
                </v-icon>
              </v-btn>
            </v-col>
          </v-row>

          略
        </v-card>
      </v-stepper-content>

<v-stepper-content step="3" class="pa-3">
        <div class="item-list">
          <v-card
            v-for="(item, index) in mergeList"
            :key="item"
            outlined
            color="grey lighten-3"
            style="margin-bottom: 2vh;">
            <v-row>
              <v-col cols="12" class="center" style="padding-bottom: 0; margin-top: 1vh;">{{ item }}</v-col>
            </v-row>
            <v-row>
              <v-col cols="4" class="pr-0">
                <input
                  @change="inputunitplice(index)"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="単価"
                  inputmode="numeric"
                  pattern="^[1-9][0-9]*$"
                  class="center"
                  style="width: inherit;">
              </v-col>
              <v-col cols="2" class="pl-0" style="text-align: center;">
                <select @change="inputunit(index)">
                  <option disabled selected value="default">単位∇</option>
                  <option
                    v-for="item in unitItems"
                    :value="item"
                    :key="item"
                    class="center"
                  >{{ item }}
                  </option>
                </select>
              </v-col>
              <v-col cols="4" class="pr-0">
                <input
                  @change="inputplice(index)"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="金額"
                  inputmode="numeric"
                  pattern="^[1-9][0-9]*$"
                  class="center"
                  style="width: inherit;">
              </v-col>
              <v-col cols="2" class="pl-0">
                <p style="margin-bottom: 0;">円</p>
              </v-col>
            </v-row>
          </v-card>
        </div> 

      </v-stepper-content>
```

[image: 27行目辺り→野菜の名前という日本語が表示されている 31~34が本来step3の内容が表示されるはず。単位▽や円といった情報が表示されるはず…？]